# maximize textarea font size for ckeditor

Tags: asp.net, css, ckeditor

I have spent hours trying to maximize textarea font size for ckeditor 4.0.1 (revision d02739be4b) with no use. I have made all tricks and tweaks which are :

1- editing skeditor/skin.moono/editor.css

2- editing ckeditor/contents.css

3-changing font size from property window

After all these attempts the font is still small.

Comment: You can inspect textarea of ckeditor 4.0.1 css using firebug.

Comment: You are searching for this http://ckeditor.com/addon/font

Comment: whats the class name ?

Comment: if i try to edit it with firebug you need in common.css in line 22 add to .cke_editable font-size bigger from 13px

Comment: you mean content.css ? I changed the font size to 16 with no use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had similar issue in CKEditor 5 (but with changing the height of the text area), I finally was able to solve it according to this: 
[How to set the height of CKEditor 5 (Classic Editor)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559354/how-to-set-the-height-of-ckeditor-5-classic-editor)
After inspecting the text area I added these lines to css:

```
    .ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

I Hope this would help.