# How to set the height of CKEditor 5 (Classic Editor)

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

In CKEditor 4 to change the editor height there was a configuration option: [config.height](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-height).

How do I change the height of CKEditor 5? (the Classic Editor)

Answer (score 178):

Answering my own question as it might help others.

CKEditor 5 no longer comes with a configuration setting to change its height.
The height can be easily controlled with CSS.

There is one tricky thing though, if you use the [*Classic Editor*](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/overview.html#classic-editor):

```html
<div id="editor1"></div>
```

```js
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor1' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        // console.log( editor );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

Then the Classic Editor will hide the original element (with id `editor1`) and render next to it. That's why changing height of `#editor1` via CSS will not work.

The simplified HTML structure, after CKEditor 5 (the Classic Editor) renders, looks as follows:

```html
<!-- This one gets hidden -->
<div id="editor1" style="display:none"></div> 
<div class="ck-reset ck-editor..." ...>
    <div ...>
        <!-- This is the editable element -->
        <div class="ck-blurred ck-editor__editable ck-rounded-corners ck-editor__editable_inline" role="textbox" aria-label="Rich Text Editor, main" contenteditable="true">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In reality the HTML is much more complex, because the whole CKEditor UI is rendered. However the most important element is the "editing area" (or "editing box") marked with a `ck-editor__editable_inline` class:

```html
<div class="... ck-editor__editable ck-editor__editable_inline ..."> ... </div>
```

The "editing area" is the white rectangle where one can enter the text. So to style / change the height of the editing area, it is enough to target the editable element with CSS:

```html
<style>
.ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Nice one @Wiktor Walc :)

Comment: Do you know of a way to give a `class`, `id` and most importantly a `name` to the ck5 element? My `Zend_Form_Validation` trips, because the input is hidden and not filled in. It is also very important I can access the value directly in `Zend_Form` so I need the name of the input to be set as I (and Zend) see fit.

Comment: .ck-editor__editable class have many elements. use `.ck-editor__editable[role="textbox"]` selector.

Comment: doesn't work... .ck-editor__editable[role="textbox"]

Comment: Dropping in `document.querySelectorAll('.ck-editor__editable_inline').forEach(el => {
                el.style.minHeight = "200px";
            });` in the ClassicEditor.then() callback will format it with JS once it's loaded

Comment: Would have been nice if you could control the height dynamically with etc tailwind... by setting the height on the init element... but no thats not possible i guess... annoying, really thinking about switching editor

Answer (score 51):

[Setting the height via a global stylesheet.](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/builds/guides/integration/frameworks/angular.html#setting-the-height-via-a-global-stylesheet)
Just add to your common .css file (like style.css):

```
.ck-editor__editable {
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

Answer (score 39):

In the case of **ReactJS**.

```
<CKEditor
    editor={ClassicEditor}
    data="<p>Hello from CKEditor 5!</p>"
    onInit={(editor) => {
        // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
        // console.log("Editor is ready to use!", editor);
        editor.editing.view.change((writer) => {
        writer.setStyle(
            "height",
            "200px",
            editor.editing.view.document.getRoot()
        );
        });
    }}
/>
```

Comment: Doesn't work with e.g. `100%` height, but I can work around it. Thanks.

Comment: I am using CK-Editor5, and  had to use ```onReady``` instead of ```onInit```

Comment: @arslanshahab After using onReady instead of onInit  It's working for me. Thank You!

Comment: Maybe you want to use ```min-height``` instead of ```height```. This is for more efficient.

Answer (score 17):

From CKEditor 5 version 22 the proposed programmatic solutions are not working. Here it is how I get the work done:

```js
ClassicEditor.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ) )
    .then( editor => {
        editor.ui.view.editable.element.style.height = '500px';
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

```css
.ck-editor__editable {min-height: 500px;}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="editor">Hi world!</textarea>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/22.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Comment: The first method with ``editor.ui.view.editable.element.style.height`` wont work, since after focusing on the editor, the height is back to normal.
The second method with CSS is not considering a "programmatical" way!!

Answer (score 16):

```
editor.ui.view.editable.editableElement.style.height = '300px';
```

Comment: This is a "code-only-answer" at best and not appreciated. But actually I think it is "not an answer" at all. Could you explain how mean this to be an answer which actually helps solve OPs problem?

Comment: Actually this is a very good answer. At least it helped me a lot. But you need to combine that row with the code provided by OP. You should add this line to the "then" block, so it looks like this:
`ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor1' ) )
    .then( editor => {
       editor.ui.view.editable.editableElement.style.height = '300px';
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );` This basically selects the editor HTML element and assigns the height property directly on it.

Comment: This no longer works with latest version of CKEditor 5. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559354/how-to-set-the-height-of-ckeditor-5-classic-editor/56550285#56550285 for an updated snippet that works.

Comment: editor.ui.view.editable._editableElement.style.height='200px';

Comment: I guess now the correct path is `editor.ui.view.editable.element.style.height`, `editableElement` probably renamed to `element`

Comment: This is not working, since after focusing on the editable area, the height is back to normal.

Answer (score 13):

If you wish to do this programatically, the best way to do it is to use a Plugin. You can easily do it as follows. The following works with CKEditor 5 version 12.x

```js
function MinHeightPlugin(editor) {
  this.editor = editor;
}

MinHeightPlugin.prototype.init = function() {
  this.editor.ui.view.editable.extendTemplate({
    attributes: {
      style: {
        minHeight: '300px'
      }
    }
  });
};

ClassicEditor.builtinPlugins.push(MinHeightPlugin);
ClassicEditor
    .create( document.querySelector( '#editor1' ) )
    .then( editor => {
      // console.log( editor );
    })
    .catch( error => {
      console.error( error );
    });
```

Or if you wish to add this to a custom build, you can use the following plugin.

```js
class MinHeightPlugin extends Plugin {
    init() {
        const minHeight = this.editor.config.get('minHeight');
        if (minHeight) {
            this.editor.ui.view.editable.extendTemplate({
                attributes: {
                    style: {
                        minHeight: minHeight
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This adds a new configuration to the CKEditor called "minHeight" that will set the editor minimum height which can be used like this.

```js
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector( '#editor1' ), {
      minHeight: '300px'
    })
    .then( editor => {
        // console.log( editor );
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

Answer (score 11):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.ck-editor__editable {
    min-height: 200px !important;
}
```

Comment: This worked well for me. But I also added max-height. It's now fixed size and it scrolls automatically.

Comment: Use !important wisely & sparsely :)

Answer (score 8):

I tried to set the height and width on the config but it just didn't work on the `classic Editor`.
I was able to change the height of the editor **programmatically** on Vue by doing this.

```js
mounted() {
    const root = document.querySelector('#customer_notes');

    ClassicEditor.create(root, config).then(editor=>{
        // After mounting the application change the height
        editor.editing.view.change(writer=>{
            writer.setStyle('height', '400px', editor.editing.view.document.getRoot());
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use css:

```
.ck.ck-editor__main .ck-content {
    height: 239px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add this to your global stylesheet, this will increase the size of the CKEditor :)

```
.ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 500px;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add it to the `style` tag.

```html
<style>
 .ck-editor__editable
 {
    min-height: 150px !important;
    max-height: 400px !important;
 }
</style>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 3):

If its in latest version of Angular say 12 or 12+. We can add below style to your components style file.

`:host ::ng-deep .ck-editor__editable_inline { min-height: 300px; }`

Answer (score 2):

As for configuring the width of the CKEditor 5:

CKEditor 5 no longer comes with a configuration setting to change its width but its width can be easily controlled with CSS.

To set width of the editor (including toolbar and editing area) it is enough to set width of the main container of the editor (with `.ck-editor` class):

```html
<style>
.ck.ck-editor {
    max-width: 500px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: I am not getting any result when adding this css to my angular 6 component!

Comment: For anybody struggling with it, please see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52485082/2043175

Answer (score 2):

Simply you can add this to your CSS file

```
.ck-editor__editable {min-height: 150px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this **CSS** in your **global CSS file** and the magic will happen. **CkEditor** is full of unsolved mysteries.

```
.ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

Comment: This is the only suggestion that worked for me in my Angular 10 app.

Answer (score 1):

Use `max-height` and `min-height` both. Beacuse `max-height` give scroll bar option after reached maximum mention height. Where `min-height` give static height to `<textarea>`.

> .ck-editor__editable {
> max-height: 400px; min-height:400px;}

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery and the CKEditor 5 has to be applied to a textarea, there is a "quick and dirty" solution.

The condition:

```
<textarea name='my-area' id='my_textarea_id'>
```

If you use jQuery the Editor call could be:

```js
var $ref=$('#my_textarea_id');

ClassicEditor
    .create( $ref[0] ,{
        // your options
    } )
    .then( editor => {
        // Set custom height via jQuery by appending a scoped style
        $('<style type="text/css" scoped>.ck-editor .ck-editor__editable_inline {min-height: 200px !important;}</style>').insertAfter($ref);

    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
```

In other words, after rendering, you can address the same element used to build the editor and append after a scoped style tag with containing the custom height.

```
$('<style type="text/css" scoped>.ck-editor .ck-editor__editable_inline {min-height: 200px !important;}</style>').insertAfter($ref);
```

If you like to use a function (or some class method) to do this, you need something like this:

```js
var editorBuildTo = function(id,options){
  var options=options || {};
  //Height represents the full widget height including toolbar
  var h = options.height || 250; //Default height if not set
  var $ref = $('#'+id);
  
  h=(h>40?h-40:h);//Fix the editor height if the toolbar is simple

  ClassicEditor
    .create( $ref[0] ,{
        // your options
    } )
    .then( editor => {
        // Set custom height via jQuery
        $('<style type="text/css" scoped>.ck-editor .ck-editor__editable_inline {min-height: '+h+'px !important;}</style>').insertAfter($ref);
    } )
    .catch( error => {
        console.error( error );
    } );
}

editorBuildTo('my_textarea_id',{
  height:175,
  // other options as you need
});
```

This works well for me

Answer (score 0):

```
1.resource/assets/js/app.js
=================================
2.paste this code 
=================================

 require('./bootstrap');
//integrate
window.ClassicEditor = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic');



============================================
3.write on terminal
============================================
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
npm run watch

=======================================
4.in blade file
=======================================
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <title></title>

  <body>

    <form action="{{route('admin.category.store')}}" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    @csrf
      <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <label  class="form-control-label">Description:</label>
        <textarea name="description" id="editor" class="form-control" row="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
   </form>
<script>
$(function () {
  ClassicEditor
.create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ), {
    toolbar: [ 'heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'link', 'bulletedList', 'numberedList', 'blockQuote' ],
    heading: {
        options: [
            { model: 'paragraph', title: 'Paragraph', class: 'ck-heading_paragraph' },
            { model: 'heading1', view: 'h1', title: 'Heading 1', class: 'ck-heading_heading1' },
            { model: 'heading2', view: 'h2', title: 'Heading 2', class: 'ck-heading_heading2' }
        ]
    }
} )
.catch( error => {
    console.log( error );
} );
})

</script>


  </body>
</html>
```

[click to show image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvkmD.png)

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Jaskaran Singh React solution. I also needed to ensure it was 100% height to it's parent. I achieved this by assigning a `ref` called "modalComponent" and further adding this code:

```
editor.editing.view.change(writer => {

   let reactRefComponentHeight = this.modalComponent.current.offsetHeight
   let editorToolbarHeight = editor.ui.view.toolbar.element.offsetHeight
   let gapForgiveness = 5
   let maximizingHeight = reactRefComponentHeight - editorToolbarHeight - gapForgiveness

   writer.setStyle(
      'height',
      `${maximizingHeight}px`,
      editor.editing.view.document.getRoot()
   )
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This CSS Method works for me:

```
.ck-editor__editable {
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this just adding in my layout page

```
<style>
       .ck-content{
           height: 250px;
       }
</style>
```

Hope i help someone :D

Comment: please add more description

Answer (score 0):

For this particular version https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.16.0/standard/ckeditor.js,
the below code block worked for me.
`.cke_contents { height: 500px !important; }`
I guess the difference is just the fact that is it in plural.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it worked for me
Add a ck class and write style like below:

```
<style>
    .ck {
        height: 200px;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using plugin here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56550285/1538014) I came up with this

```
let rows: number;
export class MinHeightPlugin {
    constructor(public editor) {
    }
    init = function () {
        this.editor.ui.view.editable.extendTemplate({
            attributes: {
                style: {
                    minHeight: (rows * 40) + 'px',
                }
            }
        });
    };
}
export const MinHeightPluginFactory = (rowss: number): typeof MinHeightPlugin => {
    rows = rowss;
    return MinHeightPlugin;
};
```

and the usage(4 rows each rows is considered 40px height):

```
 this.editor.builtinPlugins.push(MinHeightPluginFactory(4));
```

I couldn't manage to make `rows` variable local to `MinHeightPlugin`, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 400px;
}
```

**This makes height change for every editor used across all components. So it doesn't work in my case.**

Answer (score 0):

In order to enable both `rich text editor` and `source mode` to have the same height, use the following CSS:

```
.ck-source-editing-area,
.ck-editor__editable {
    min-height: 500px;
}

.ck-editor__main {
    height: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    border: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote some `scss` overrides to force CKEditor 5 to take all of the available height of its container element without loosing scroll capability.

```scss
.ck-editor {

  height: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  .ck-editor__top {
    flex-shrink: 1;
  }

  .ck-editor__main {
    flex-grow: 1;
    position: relative;

    .ck-editor__editable, .ck-source-editing-area {
      position: absolute;
      top:0;
      left:0;
      right:0;
      bottom:0;
    }

  }

}
```

This way CKEditor will always consume full height of its parent where you can easily control the outer constraints for each instance placement.

Answer (score 0):

please use this style for global

```
.ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 500px !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

For those who've been looking for a solution to dynamically adjust the height of CKEditor 5 and add resize capabilities, I'm excited to share a new plugin I've developed: https://github.com/pikulinpw/ckeditor5-resizableheight

**Key Features**:

- Dynamically adjust the height of the CKEditor instance.
- Option to resize the editor, providing a more flexible editing environment.
- Set specific height options or allow the plugin to determine the height based on content.
- Seamless integration with CKEditor 5.

It's now available on npm and easy to integrate with your existing CKEditor setup. Check out the README for installation and usage instructions.

Feedback, bug reports, and contributions are welcome. Let's make our CKEditor experience even better!

Answer (score -1):

```
In Case of react js
   <CKEditor
      toolbar = {
                 [
                     'heading',
                     'bold',
                     'Image'
                  ]
                }
      editor={ClassicEditor}
      data={this.state.description}//your state where you save data
      config={{ placeholder: "Enter description.." }}
      onChange={(event, editor) => {
                     const data = editor.getData();
                     this.setState({
                           description : data
                      })
               }}
      onReady={(editor)=>{
                  editor.editing.view.change((writer) => {
                  writer.setStyle(
                     //use max-height(for scroll) or min-height(static)
                     "min-height", 
                     "180px",
                     editor.editing.view.document.getRoot()
                  );
               });
               }}
   />
```

Comment: first of all, use onReady instead of onInit and second use max-height or min-height to set the height of ckeditor,Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Just test it's work. Hoping help you

var editor_ = CKEDITOR.replace('content', {height: 250});

Comment: This is for CKEditor 4