# How to set CKEditor 5 height

Tags: angular, ckeditor, shadow-dom, ckeditor5

Using CKeditor angular component How to set the editor height?

According to the docs, it can be done by setting the editor style to:

```
 min-height: 500px !important;
```

But it doesn't work!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you add it to the global stylesheet the following should work:

```
.ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 500px !important;
}
```

But if you want to style through the `component.css` you need to type this:

```
:host ::ng-deep .ck-editor__editable_inline {
    min-height: 500px !important;
}
```

Comment: did you add that rule to the Ck Editor stylesheet file or to the stylesheet file of the component hosts it?

Comment: Are you sure that the style is loaded? I'm editing the `styles.css` in the angular example and it works well.

Comment: aha now it works, I was adding it to the component CSS not app styles.css ,this is wired, thank you edit the answer with your last comment

Comment: Oh. You have right, sorry for the confusion, I'll update the answer with a proper method.

Comment: If you want to use the first option and not put into your global add encapsulation none to the component. encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None