# How to add a scrollbar to Classic CKEditor 5?

Tags: angular, ckeditor5

The documentation mentions that the default behaviour of CKEditor 5 is to grow when more text is added.

However I want the editor to show a scrollbar instead of growing. How can this be done ?

Comment: Have you tried to set a max-height using CSS?

Comment: Indeed that was it !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559354/how-to-set-the-height-of-ckeditor-5-classic-editor) you can achieve this by adding `max-height` to CSS.

This way is also used in their [document demo](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/demo/#document).

```
.ck-editor__editable {
    max-height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

thanks @josefKatic for the answer :

```
.ck-editor__editable {
    min-height: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```